# Apache2 can not load wsgi.py

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

I am using an Ubuntu 14.10 X86_64 system with softwares in below:

- python 3.4
- apache2
- libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
- django1.8

I created a project by django1.8 at this path:

```
/var/www/html/koorimeo
```

I've noticed that django-admin startproject will generate a wsgi.py file by default and I haven't change its content.

I configured apache2 under the official document(How to use Django with Apache and mod_wsgi) details:

I modified 000-default.conf for I don't want to setup another Virtual Host. and This is What I added:

```
#000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
<Directory /var/www/html/koorimeo/koorimeo>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

After that I declare WSGIAlias and WSGIPythonPath in apache2.conf:

```
#apache2.conf
#I want to leave "/" for other use...
WSGIScriptAlias /koorimeo /var/www/html/koorimeo/koorimeo/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/koorimeo/koorimeo
```

After finished setting files I restarted apache2 service and login into 127.0.0.1/koorimeo, it returned a 500 error message...
I looked up the error log file and get these error message:

```
bing@k-lab:/var/log/apache2$ tail error.log
[Sat Apr 25 14:35:31.214661 2015] [:notice] [pid 16997:tid 140004070725504] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 6 max processes and 25 max threads.
[Sat Apr 25 14:35:31.214705 2015] [:notice] [pid 16997:tid 140004070725504] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp 
[Sat Apr 25 14:35:31.232634 2015] [:warn] [pid 16997:tid 140004070725504] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.4.0.
[Sat Apr 25 14:35:31.232682 2015] [:warn] [pid 16997:tid 140004070725504] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.6.
[Sat Apr 25 14:35:31.232766 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16997:tid 140004070725504] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 25 14:35:31.232786 2015] [core:notice] [pid 16997:tid 140004070725504] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Apr 25 14:35:32.234958 2015] [core:notice] [pid 16997:tid 140004070725504] AH00051: child pid 18325 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Apr 25 14:35:32.235070 2015] [core:notice] [pid 16997:tid 140004070725504] AH00051: child pid 18326 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Apr 25 14:35:34.041184 2015] [:error] [pid 18599:tid 140003960342272] [client 127.0.0.1:51134] mod_wsgi (pid=18599): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/koorimeo/koorimeo/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://localhost/
[Sat Apr 25 14:35:34.041279 2015] [:error] [pid 18599:tid 140003960342272] [client 127.0.0.1:51134] mod_wsgi (pid=18599): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/koorimeo/koorimeo/wsgi.py'., referer: http://localhost/
```

According these message I found that apache2 can not find this module:

```
/var/www/html/koorimeo/wsgi.py
```

So I copy this path and try to get me clear wheather this file do exist:

```
bing@k-lab:/var/log/apache2$ ls /var/www/html/koorimeo/koorimeo/wsgi.py -l
```

and the system returned this message which told me that the file is truly exists...

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bing bing 389  4月 25 14:21 /var/www/html/koorimeo/koorimeo/wsgi.py
```

And I also make sure that I've installed libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3, I did find wsgi.so in proper location.

I've found wsgi.load in modes-enable and pointed the wsgi.so in right place:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

So... I am confused...

Please tell me why can't apache2 find this **wsgi.py** file?

Comment: No, the error doesn't say it can't find it; it says it had problems loading the file. That's probably because of dependencies; have you installed Django? And why aren't you using a virtualenv?

Comment: I am new to django and i even do not know what virtualenv is....

Comment: I can sure I've installed Django with source code.. I downloaded the tar.gz package, then extract and use the command "sudo python setup.py install" to finished the installation process

Comment: I just know python2 is the default environment of linux system. But how to solve this dependencies problem? may I add and head of "/usr/bin/env python3"?

Comment: Are you using a `virtualenv` ? This would make things easier for you, specially when dealing with multiple versions of python

Comment: Thank you friend. The issue is solved although I still don't know where i was wrong. I restarted the project and copy codes to new folder the web page could be displayed well...

Comment: And thanks to Paco too. I am start to read user guide now:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove mod_python from Apache if you are not using it.

Your mod_wsgi module was compiled for Python 3.4.0, but mod_python was compiled for 2.7.6. Because mod_python is using a different version it is overriding what Python version is used and this will stop mod_wsgi from working.

Read the many sections in the documentation starting at:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Using_ModPython_and_ModWsgi

Comment: Thank you! With out your tip, I will never notice this log message... and How careless I am that even never keep an eye on that information...